# How do I calculate the past value of a loan?

Tags: loans, calculation

I have a loan that was originally $100,000.
It is worth $116,971.41 today.
It has been accruing 6% annual interest, compounded daily.
I do not know the start date.

How do I calculate what the value of this loan was 90 days ago?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interest would be calculated as

```
A= P * (1+r/n)^nt
```

where A=ending amount, P=principal, r=rate, n=number of times compounded per T, t=time rate is over (usually year).

So solving for P where A=116971.41, r=.06, n=365, t=90/365 (so nt=90) would give you

```
P = A/(1+r/n)^nt
```

You should end up with a number just over $115,250.